# I need to create a custom date format on a SSAS Microsoft Tabular model to dd-MMM-yyyy

Tags: ssas-2012

I am trying to customize the `date` in the format of `dd-MMM-yyyy` in a `Microsoft tabular model` and It does not seem to take.

It seems to go back to `general` every time I change it.

Can someone help me with a solution.

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow. In order to get better help, please share a code sample so people can localize your problem.

Comment: Where are you changing the format and what front end tool appears to be changing it back?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement and found answer over the web.
You can create a Calculated Column in your date table and use the Format function.

As an example using the AdventureWorksDW database as an example, you could create a calculated column with the following formula: `=Format([FullDateAlternateKey], "dd-MMM-yyyy")` and use it in target pivot

[Takes from Microsoft forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/014caf8e-04ed-4959-810a-894181afccab/i-need-to-create-a-custom-date-format-in-microsoft-tabular-model-ssas-2012-vs2010-can-somone?forum=sqlanalysisservices)